# how to refactor these queries in only one?

Tags: soql, queryselector

I have to transform this method using another method of type Selector. Is it possible to make only one query in this case, respecting each criterion or will I have to create 4 selector's methods?
I'm asking this because in each query the `!=` is in a different position.

```
public static List<Product2> getProduct(String color, String brand,  String model){
        
        if (brand == null || brand == ''){
            return [SELECT Color__c, Name,Id, Photo__c, ProductCode FROM Product2 WHERE Brand__c != null AND Model__c != null AND Color__c != null];
        }else{
            if (model == null || model == ''){
                return [SELECT Color__c,Name,Id, Photo__c, ProductCode FROM Product2 WHERE Brand__c = :brand AND Model__c != null AND Color__c != null];
            } else{
                if (color == null || color == ''){
                    return [SELECT Color__c,Name,Id, Photo__c, ProductCode FROM Product2 WHERE Brand__c = :brand AND Model__c = :model AND Color__c != null];
                } else{
                    return [SELECT Color__c,Name,Id, Photo__c, ProductCode FROM Product2 WHERE Brand__c = :brand AND Model__c = :model AND Color__c = :color];    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd tackle it.

```
public static List<Product2> getProduct(String color, String brand, String model){

    // create list of query clauses and add select clause
    List<String> queryParts = new List<String>{'SELECT Color__c, Name, Photo__c, ProductCode'};
    queryParts.add('FROM Product2');
    
    if(String.isNotEmpty(brand) && String.isNotEmpty(model) && String.isNotEmpty(color)){
        queryParts.add('WHERE Brand__c = \'' + brand + '\' AND Model__c = \'' + model + '\' AND Color__c = \'' + color + '\'');
    } else 
    if(String.isNotEmpty(brand) && String.isNotEmpty(model)){
        queryParts.add('WHERE Brand__c = \'' + brand + '\' AND Model__c = \'' + model + '\' AND Color__c != \'\'');
    } else
    if (String.isNotEmpty(model)){
        queryParts.add('WHERE Brand__c = \'' + brand + '\' AND Model__c = \'\' AND Color__c != \'\'');
    } else {
        queryParts.add('WHERE Brand__c = \'\' AND Model__c = \'\' AND Color__c = \'\'');
    }

    queryParts.add('WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED');

    return Database.query(String.join(' ', queryParts));

}
```

**NOTE WELL - I have not compiled this to ensure it's syntax-correct**

Answer (score 3):

This is a use case for [Dynamic Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic.htm). We can build a SOQL string, and then execute it with `Database.execute`.

```
   String query = 'SELECT Color__c, Name, Photo__c, ProductCode FROM Product2 WHERE ';
   String[] filters = new String[0];
   if(String.isNotBlank(brand)) {
     filters.add('Brand__c = :brand');
   } else {
     filters.add('Brand__c != null');
   }
   if(String.isNotBlank(model)) {
     filters.add('Model__c = :model');
   } else {
     filters.add('Model__c != null');
   }
   if(String.isNotBlank(color)) {
     filters.add('Color__c = :color');
   } else {
     filters.add('Color__c != null');
   }
   query += String.join(filters, ' AND ');
   return Database.query(query);
```

As a bonus, you can now specify any of the 8 possible conditions (e.g. a model without a brand), rather than the four you coded for. We also used binding to avoid [SOQL injection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_sql_injection.htm).

Comment: But it is a bad practice in Selector Methods put If, For, While etc, isn't it?

Comment: @Caroline It depends on your point of view, I guess, but I'd rather have one method than 8 nearly identical methods. Also, that would mean the if statements would end up upstream somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm).

Construct a `String` variable that contains your complete SOQL query text, then use `Database.query()` to execute it.

Example

```
String qry = 'SELECT Color__c, Name,Id, Photo__c, ProductCode FROM Product2 WHERE Brand__c != null';
return Database.query(qry);
```

If you need to include variable values in the WHERE clauses, remember to include escaped single quotes surrounding the value:

```
String brand = 'Acme';
String qry = 'SELECT Color__c, Name,Id, Photo__c, ProductCode FROM Product2 WHERE Brand__c = \'' + brand + '\'';
return Database.query(qry);
```

Comment: Nice, but you forgot about SOQL injection, etc.